# I can't run my react-native app on ios Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having a real issue with running my react-native ios app. I installed Xcode (version 8.3.3) and all the other basic dependencies needed, all I did was:

```
    react-native init AwesomeProject
    cd AwesomeProject
    react-native run-ios
```

And what happens is the AwesomeProject app opens for a second then closes. I also tried running it through xcode and get the same problem, although it is atleast reporting an error of:

```
2017-09-04 20:38:11.369 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:188] 

Initializing <RCTCxxBridge: 0x6000001a0540> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000000a9a20>, executor: (null))
2017-09-04 20:38:11.390 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:114] Class RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2017-09-04 20:38:11.404 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:301] Running application AwesomeProject ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-09-04 20:38:11.467 AwesomeProject[10363:1261593] -[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa383534303930327
2017-09-04 20:38:11.509 AwesomeProject[10363:1261593] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa383534303930327'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e4f4b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d3aa141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e564134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e47b840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e47b3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010c7653f4 -[RCTMultipartStreamReader emitProgress:contentLength:final:callback:] + 244
    6   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010c765bea -[RCTMultipartStreamReader readAllPartsWithCompletionCallback:progressCallback:] + 1610
    7   AwesomeProject                      0x000000010c7b551c -[RCTMultipartDataTask URLSession:streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:] + 444
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000010df54c51 __88-[NSURLSession delegate_streamTask:didBecomeInputStream:outputStream:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 51
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010ceb43b7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010ceb40bb -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010ceb2877 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010ceae5fc __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001121d605c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001121b494f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 221
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001121b5669 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1084
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001121b7ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001121b7bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011256d5a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011256d07d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

And I then get brought to this page with the following Thread 8: signal SIGABRT error:

```
->  0x112538d42 <+10>: jae    0x112538d4c               ; <+20>
```

I have googled a lot with regards to the NSEXCEPTION yet I still cannot seem to even run my app. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's an issue with react-native 0.48.0.

You can follow the thread below, it should be fixed with 0.48.1.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15768

Edit: I can confirm 0.48.1 works fine. Update using:

> npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
>
> react-native-git-upgrade